# I got a Problem with the Technical-Analysis-Library

Tags: python, technical-indicator

I searched several Days for an answer without success, thats why Im Here with the hope of getting that Problem solved.
First of all, I am kinda new to Python, so if you find the answer why I get so strange values, it would be lovely, if you can explain what causes those "errors".
As you can see indicators like "RSI" or the K&D Lines from the "Stochastic RSI" have a Value and work fine. On the other hand indicators Like "WilliamsR" or the "EMA" don't.
Down below is the Code to Hopefully reproduce the "error values" on %R and EMA.

Thanks in advance and stay safe.

### My Code

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import ta
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = yf.download('ETH-USD', start='2022-06-15', interval='5m' )

df['%K'] = ta.momentum.stoch(df.High, df.Low ,df.Close , 14 ,3)

df['%D'] = df['%K'].rolling(3).mean()

df['RSI'] = ta.momentum.rsi(df.Close ,14)

df['%R'] = ta.momentum.WilliamsRIndicator(df.High, df.Low ,df.Close ,21)

df['EMA'] = ta.trend.EMAIndicator(df.Close, 13)

df.dropna(inplace=False)
```

### Outputs

Value of %R
`<ta.momentum.WilliamsRIndicator object at 0x00...`

Value of EMA
`<ta.trend.EMAIndicator object at 0x000001C0017...`

### Image on Imgur

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5e8x.png)

Answer (score 0):

About EMA: you should add .ema_indicator()
`df['EMA'] = ta.trend.EMAIndicator(df.Close, 13).ema_indicator()`
About WiliamsInd: try to replace with WILLR (I use 'talib as t', not 'ta' here):
`df['%R'] = t.WILLR(df.High, df.Low ,df.Close ,21)`